# Validar una clase css en un tpl mediante un if

Tags: javascript, css, condiciones, prestashop1.7

tengo el siguiente problema, en la parte de envío modifiqué mi archivo tpl para que se muestre la leyenda *PENDIENTE* si el cliente no ha iniciado sesión y aparte quiero validar en la condición que un el elemento div tenga la clase #checkout-delivery-step.**-unreachable** para validar esto agregué el siguiente fragmento de código en mi tpl:

```
{if $subtotal && $subtotal.type !== 'tax'}
      <div class="cart-summary-line cart-summary-subtotals" id="cart-subtotal-{$subtotal.type}">
        <span class="label">{$subtotal.label}</span>
        
              //Código que agregué
                {if $subtotal.type === 'shipping' && {$customer.is_logged} !== '1' && #checkout-delivery-step.-unreachable(se que esto no es correcto pero es lo que quiero lograr)}
                  <span class="value" style="font-style:italic;">PENDIENTE</span>                      
                {else}
                <span class="value">{$subtotal.value}</span>
                {/if}
      </div>
    {/if}
```

¿Existe alguna manera en que pueda validar dentro de ese mismo if que #checkout-delivery-step contenga la clase **-unreachable**?

También intente hacerlo con un script de la siguiente manera:

```
    var intro = document.getElementById('checkout-delivery-step');
    if (document.querySelector("#checkout-delivery-step.-unreachable")) {
      intro.style.backgroundColor = '#FF00FF';
      document.querySelector("#cart-subtotal-shipping span.value").innerHTML = " <span class="value">PENDIENTE 2</span>";
    } else {
      intro.style.backgroundColor = '#feb333';
document.querySelector("#cart-subtotal-shipping span.value").innerHTML = " <span class="value">{$subtotal.value}</span>"; //no muestra el valor de la variable ya que viene en otro archivo
    }
```

Al hacerlo con el script lo único que necesito validar es que el elemento #checkout-delivery-step contenga la clase -unreachable el detalle con esto es que necesito utilizar una variable que se llama {$subtotal.value} la cual esta en el tpl y el script esta en otra parte, otro detalle que me pasa con el script es que me hace lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me dice que el subtotal es de 22,18 pero en Total me dice que son 30,30 esto se debe a que a pesar de que en el envío dice PENDIENTE, se le esta asignando un valor y eso no esta bien, debe de decir en el Total 22,18 por tal motivo y para no complicar más las cosas quiero encontrar alguna manera de poder validar eso en el if que les mostré al inicio. Estos archivos son de prestashop 1.7.6.5

Ayudaaaaa :(

Answer (score 0):

Para solucionar lo de tu total y subtotal debes modificar 2 archivos respecto a tu template podria ser algo asi:

`themes\classic\templates\checkout\_partials\cart-summary-totals.tpl`
`themes\classic\templates\checkout\_partials\order-confirmation-table.tpl`

Esto es debido a que ese valor se despliega en tu carrito y también en tu proceso de pago, en el primer archivo vas a encontrar mas o menos lo siguiente:

```
<div class="card-block cart-summary-totals">

  {block name='cart_summary_total'}
    <div class="cart-summary-line cart-total">
      <span class="label">{$cart.totals.total.label} {$cart.labels.tax_short}</span>
      <span class="value">{$cart.totals.total.value}</span>
      <span class="label">Total (con IVA)</span>
      <span class="value">{$cart.totals.total.amount + $cart.subtotals.tax.amount} {$currency.sign}</span>
    </div>
  {/block}
```

Y en el segundo documento encuentras el bloque de código:

```
        <td><span>TOTAL (con IVA)</span></td>
       <td><span>{$totals.total.amount + $subtotals.tax.amount} {$currency.sign} 
       </span></td>
```

En ese bloque modificamos lo que quieres ir mostrando en el total, recuerda que estas variables van a cambiar respecto a las necesidades de tu tienda por lo tanto hago referencia a las variables que puedes usar para facilitarte ese trabajo [SMARTY GLOBAL VARIABLES](https://www.themebooster.com/prestashop-tutorials/prestashop-1-7-smarty-global-variables/)

Respecto a la leyenda pendiente, aconsejaría que modificaras esta leyenda directamente desde `las traducciones` del tema en general, si el cliente no ha seleccionado un método de envío entonces que le muestre esa leyenda, eso lo haría directamente Prestashop y no comprometes el backend para futuras actualizaciones.

Esperando que te ayude un poquito lo que buscas.